# what should I do about my pineapple plant?

Tags: plant-health

[image]

The leaves are very light brown it’s not a healthy green color. One other plant has black spots in the center.

Answer (score 2):

It looks pretty close to dead. I would throw it out , buy another pineapple, cut off the top and root it. They root very easily : when watering be sure to put some water in the center . Bromeliads seem to need water in the center more than in the soil.

Answer (score 1):

The pineapple is a member of the Bromeliad family, Ananas comosus. Keep this one watered just in case but start another one. Cut off the top with about an inch of the pineapple. Set it aside for a few days for the moist pineapple to dry up. Plant it in a well draining soil. Water from the top but keep the soil damp. The pineapple develops a good root system but benefits from water in the crown.